# Pl-Sql User Connection

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I've been starting oracle on my job. But i've been using MS all the time. Now i have problem on User-Shema structure. I tryed a create table with sql query, but table had been created in somewhere else then i wanted. (I've already created a user named LPA) I just wrote the query, and table is in the (GeneralDatabase) Tablespaces->Users->(Here). I want to create a table in LPA schema, under the table folder. I've been searching for it but i could'nt get it. So need some help please.

PS:I found that i need to connect with user, than write to query with TS_LPA(Thats my tablespace). But i also cant connect with the user LPA.(We can say this is my first problem)

Comment: Yes, when you're connected as user 'LPA' and you create a table, it belongs to user 'LPA' and it's in the LPA schema. Normally the tablespace is set as the default for the user so you don't need to care about it. (btw none of this is PL/SQL - that's the programming language.)

Comment: Actually i know the query that i'm going to use after connection. The problem is; i've tryed all the query i could found for connection. (connect LPA/password; should've work i think :( ) But there is same error all the time that i tryed connection:"invalid sql statement" So i still cant connect as LPA.

Comment: So your question is how to use your desktop tool to connect to your development database?

Comment: Not exactly. İ'm connecting manufacturing database on my tool. But problem is;when i try creating table, its creating in manufacturing db tablespaces. LPA is my user in manufacturing and im trying to design my tables in it. I dont know maybe i misunderstood it.

Comment: If you're connected as LPA then `create table test (id int)` will create table LPA.TEST. If it's working but just not using the tablespace you want, then specify `tablespace ts_lpa` at the end of the `create` statement, and maybe have a word with the DBA about getting that made the default for the LPA user.

Comment: I've already tryed it. It's creating in tablespace, but i want to create it tables folder witch in same segment with tablespace folder (same area) I think i dont know where i need to look for solution. How can i send u ss? (I'm new here)

Comment: I don't know what tool you're using but I'm guessing what it's telling you is the table isn't in the schema you expected. What user are you actually connecting as?

Comment: By the way i was trying to say which not witch :)

Comment: Using Pl-sql Developer (has purple icon). U are asking the first connection i think and im pretty sure thats not about it. I think i cant understand or cant tell my problem (i said im new on oracle and this schema-user structure hard for me now) İm gonna try for a while. After this discustion im thinking thats cause of my  
inexperience. So i dont want to take your time anymore. But thanks for your time and help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle there is no "dbo" or default schema, in case that is what you are looking for. You must specify the target user account when you connect (log in) to the database, and that account will be used as the default schema for all of your subsequent actions. (This is similar to a home directory in Linux, where if I log in as `williamr` and create a file, it will belong to `williamr` and not some generic default account.)

In your case I suspect you are connecting as SYS or similar, in which case your table now belongs to SYS (or whoever you are connected as). You'll need to drop it and try again.

If you don't want to post the connect string you used to connect initially for some reason, then execute the following query to see your current schema:

```
select user, sys_context('userenv','current_schema') from dual;
```

(Normally `user` and `sys_context('userenv','current_schema')` will be the same, but worth double-checking.)

In PL/SQL Developer you can only issue `connect` commands from a Command window (not a SQL window). Alternatively you can use the 'log on' menu tool, or Session > Set Main Connection from the menu, or (best if you want to reuse it later) Tools > Define Connections, which has a 'Test...' button to validate a new connection. You'll need the username, password and database service name (not just username and password).

Comment: Mr. Robertson hi. I got it. (Finally) You were right. I've realized that i was in another user at that moment. But there was also LPA user on tools interface and i could controll it. Also I found some subject and ex on web -about connecting as user. I did focus on that. Sorry for my stubbornness. And thank u again.

Answer (score 0):

connect with LPA user.

specify the schema name before table name.

```
create table LPA.tbl_name(col1 datatype1,....);
```

Comment: One or the other, but not both, surely? You can only create tables in another schema if you've been granted `create any table` privilege, which is not normally granted to developers as it's a pretty serious privilege.

Comment: I gave all privilege to the user when i create it

Comment: Mr. Mishra, i know the query that im going to use after connection. But i couldnt connect as LPA. I've been trying it with sql query (Connect LPA/password;) but it doesnt work. Im wonder if i walk wrong way. Could you tell how im going to connect as LPA?

Comment: Problem solved. That was my foult and actually it is a little embarrassing. I focused on something wrong. But im learning oracle :) Thank u all for help and time